# returning an array from ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

trying to get 2 values from an ajax call, cant seem to breakup the results back form the call
the ajax

```
 $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              url: 'inc/getuser.php?q='+boxnum,
              success:function(data){

                alert(lname);

              }
            });
```

the php

```
$datas = $database->select("Drivers", "*", [
        "id" => $q]);
        if (count($datas)>0) {
            foreach($datas as $data){
                $fname=$data['first_name'];
                $lname=$data['last_name'];
            }
            $rdata = array(
                'fname'=> $fname,
                'lname'=> $lname
                                );
            echo $rdata; //$datas['first_name'] 
        } else {
            echo 'no datas';
        }
```

trying to find the lastname only.
thank in advance
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this:

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   dataType: 'json', // <-- specify that your return type should be JSON
   url: 'inc/getuser.php?q='+boxnum,
   success:function(data){
      if (data.fname && data.lname) {
         var firstName = data.fname;
         var lastName  = data.lname;
      }
   }
});
```

when working with arrays you need to use `JSON` data type.

Your PHP: `echo json_encode($rdata);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode()` function in your PHP file

```
      echo json_encode($rdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode() in PHP to serialize your data first as Paramore has explained.

In javascript your success function callback has a parameter of "data", "lname" is not defined in that context so to access fname and lname you need to do like so:

`data.lname`
`data.fname`